# Function inlined in the header increments the wrong attribute: subtle bug

Tags: c++, header-files, compiler-optimization, compiler-flags, inlining

**The setup** (source files are listed at the bottom). There is a `Counters` class with 2 counter members and 2 methods to increment them and a 3rd extra `#ifndef NDEBUG`-guarded "debug" counter and its incrementer. These incrementer methods are provided through additional functions defined in their respective headers.

**The bug**. This is a contrived scenario, but the "`-DNDEBUG`" compilation flag is provided for only one of the two headers. The effect of this is that the wrong counter is incremented in the final program: `main.cpp` prints:

```
$ CFLAGS='-DNDEBUG' make; ./main

> Counter 1: 0
> Counter 2: 4
> Debug all counters: 7
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "counters.hpp"
#include "increment1.hpp"
#include "increment2.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

Counters c;

increment1(c);increment1(c);increment1(c);
increment2(c);increment2(c);increment2(c);increment2(c);

cout << "Counter 1: " << c.getCounter1() << endl;
cout << "Counter 2: " << c.getCounter2() << endl;

#ifndef NDEBUG
cout << "Debug all counters: " << c.getDebugAllCounters() << endl;
#endif

return 0;}
```

Purportedly, this is because when `increment1.cpp` receives the "no-debug" version of the `Counters` class and is therefore unaware of the extra debug counter, which is now the 1st member of the struct, and erroneously increments it instead of `m_counter`. (This is easily checked by moving the the debug counter below the two main counters)

I'm imagining that this is because `clang++ -c -DNDEBUG -O2 increment1.cpp` builds `increment1.cpp` (see Makefile below) with a model of `Counters` which only has two (instead of three) classes, but in the final `main.cpp` as well as `increment2.cpp` there are three memebers. So

```
// increment1.cpp
#include "counters.hpp"
void increment1(Counters& counters){counters.inc1();}
```

actually turns into *pseudocode*

```
// .. 
// .. whole non-debug version of Counters
// ..
void increment1(Counters& counters){
       [the Counters instance]->[first_member]++;}
}
```

### Q1

How does this inlining of the class method into a function call take place? Does the differing names of members not matter in this case because inlining takes place at the register level? Is there a compiler flag (like `-S`) I can use to see this intermediate inlined representation?

### Q2

This error doesn't go away even if i replace all `-O2`'s with `-O0`'s in the `Makefile` or add `__attribute__((optnone))` to `inc1`. If inlining is the culprit, what am i missing?

---

```
Counters.hpp
increment1.cpp
increment1.hpp
increment2.cpp
increment2.hpp
main.cpp
```

#### Counters.hpp

```cpp
class Counters
{
private:
    #ifndef NDEBUG   
        int m_debugAllCounters;  
    #endif
    int m_counter1;
    int m_counter2;
public:
    Counters() :
    #ifndef NDEBUG 
        m_debugAllCounters(0),
    #endif
                 m_counter1(0), m_counter2(0){}
     void inc1(){
        #ifndef NDEBUG  
            m_debugAllCounters++;
        #endif
        m_counter1++;}

     void inc2(){
        #ifndef NDEBUG  
            m_debugAllCounters++;
        #endif
        m_counter2++; }

    int getCounter1() const { return m_counter1; }
    int getCounter2() const { return m_counter2; }
    #ifndef NDEBUG
    int getDebugAllCounters() const { return m_debugAllCounters; }
    #endif
};
```

#### increment1.hpp

```cpp
class Counters;
int increment1(Counters&);
```

#### increment1.cpp

```cpp
#include "counters.hpp"
void increment1(Counters& counters){counters.inc1();}
```

#### increment2.hpp

```cpp
class Counters;
int increment2(Counters&);
```

#### increment2.cpp

```cpp
#include "counters.hpp"
void increment2(Counters& counters){counters.inc2();}
```

#### Makefile

```
all: main.o increment1.o increment2.o
    clang++ -o main main.o increment1.o increment2.o

main.o: main.cpp increment1.hpp increment2.hpp counters.hpp
    clang++ -c -O2 main.cpp

increment1.o: increment1.cpp counters.hpp
    clang++ -c $(CFLAGS) -O2 increment1.cpp

increment2.o: increment2.cpp counters.hpp
    clang++ -c -O2 increment2.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o diff-flags
```

This bug is outlined in the [following article](https://www.toptal.com/c-plus-plus/c-plus-plus-understanding-compilation)("Compiling with different flags" section at the bottom).

Comment: `-DNDEBUG` changes the class ABI, all files need to be rebuilt. Just `CFLAGS='-DNDEBUG' make` doesn't rebuilt all files.

Comment: Any idea how i could inspect the ABI with and without the flag, @273K? Thanks!

Comment: You could use the [ORC](https://github.com/adobe/orc) tool to detect ODR violations.  Titus Winters would say, "Build EVERYTHING from source (dammit), with the same flags (dammit), at the same time (dammit)!"

Comment: Don't change the class ABI at the beginning if you are unable to rebuilt all files. Always append new members at the end.

Comment: "inspect" the ABI?  Look at the asm ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)), and/or print `offsetof(Counters, m_counter1)`